How to get value in an object's key using a variable referencing that key (multiple values)?
I'm trying to figure out how I can get values from my object comparing with a specific value.
For instance I have this values which is the version:
const currentVersion: "4.1.0"

but also I have this object telling me what percentage of users have the current version or above:
const versionResults = {
    "2.29.0": 1.0204081632653061,
    "4.0.0": 1.0204081632653061,
    "4.1.0": 41.83673469387756,
    "4.1.1": 56.12244897959188
}

I need to create an object that basically comparing with the current version sum the value of the object 4.1.0 & also 4.1.1.
So the final result should be like this:
results = {
  aboveOrEqualThanCurrentVersion : 97.95 //Sum of 4.1.1 & 4.1.0
  lessThanCurrentVersion : 2.05 //Sum of 4.0.0 & 2.29.0
}


I already tried different ways to achieve what i need but i can't achieve the expected result.
  function getValueByKey(object: any, row: any) {
    return object[row];
  }


I tried this to have a specific key, but when i compare
 console.log(getValueByKey(versionResults, currentVersion));


i just received
41.83673469387756


i would like to receive
[41.83673469387756, 56.12244897959188]



What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?  Please post a reproducible example of the code that you need help fixing.

"the current version or above" - Since what you have are strings, direct comparison won't do what you're looking for.  (e.g. "4.9.0" as a string is "greater than" "4.10.0" as a string)  You may need to split your strings into their component numeric parts, convert those to numbers, and compare those.

As @david mentioned above you need to do the below:

"the current version or above" - Since what you have are strings,
direct comparison won't do what you're looking for. (e.g. "4.9.0" as a
string is "greater than" "4.10.0" as a string) You may need to split
your strings into their component numeric parts, convert those to
numbers, and compare those.

Hope you are expecting something like this, Refer the code below :


const currentVersion = "4.1.0";
const versionResults = {
    "2.29.0": 1.0204081632653061,
    "4.0.0": 1.0204081632653061,
    "4.1.0": 41.83673469387756,
    "4.1.1": 56.12244897959188
};

function compareVersionsTogether(v1, v2) {
    const v1Parts = v1.split('.').map(Number);
    const v2Parts = v2.split('.').map(Number);

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (v1Parts[i] > v2Parts[i]) return 1;
        if (v1Parts[i] < v2Parts[i]) return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

function calculateVersionAdditions(versionResults, currentVersion) {
    let aboveOrEqualThanCurrentVersion = 0;
    let lessThanCurrentVersion = 0;

    for (const version in versionResults) {
        if (compareVersionsTogether(version, currentVersion) >= 0) {
            aboveOrEqualThanCurrentVersion += versionResults[version];
        } else {
            lessThanCurrentVersion += versionResults[version];
        }
    }

    return {
        aboveOrEqualThanCurrentVersion: aboveOrEqualThanCurrentVersion.toFixed(2),
        lessThanCurrentVersion: lessThanCurrentVersion.toFixed(2)
    };
}

let results = calculateVersionAdditions(versionResults, currentVersion);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results));




This is exaclty what i was looking for, i see you use the loops very impressive, thanks a lot.

Happy to help.. Appreciate if you can give an upvote :-)
